Ржавый металл — плеоназм или нет?
Ржавый металл — плеоназм или нет?

Нет, конечно!  ВО ДВОРЕ ВАЛЯЛОСЬ РЖАВОЕ ЖЕЛЕЗО,  ПОКРЫТОЕ РЖАВЧИНОЙ. Как вам плеоназм? Образцовый, можно сказать. А все остальное от лукавого)

• Я думаю, что в этом сочетании нет плеоназма.
Вот ранние упоминания из Нацкорпуса:
Впрочем, ветхому жилищу великокняжескому придавали какую-то мрачность ржавое железо решеток, ограждающих окна, тусклый мат их слюды, оправленный в свинец, преклонные теремки, уходящие в ветхий гроб свой, крышу, по которой время разбросало клочки зеленого и порыжелого моха (И. И. Лажечников. Басурман (1838));
Питая свои тела жирными испарениями города, они бледны и желты, кровь их отравлена, нервы раздражены зловещим криком ржавого металла, угрюмым воем порабощенных молний (Максим Горький. Заграничные впечатления (1906)).
• Имеется объяснение и пример толковом словаре:
ржавый
2. Покрытый ржавчиной.
Ржавый гвоздь. Ржавая крыша. Ржавая вода. Ржавый замок. Ржавое железо. Ржавая селёдка.
• Есть даже такая особая сталь — кортеновская. Она "применяется в мостостроении, судостроении, промышленном и гражданском строительстве как конструкционный материал, не нуждающийся в окраске и других видах дополнительной коррозионной защиты".
• Вот интересные образчики использования:
Ржавый металл (кортен) в частной архитектуре.
• Добавочная информация

Коррозия — это особая форма окисления, которая происходит в металлах, содержащих железо. Ржавчина образуется на металлической поверхности в виде оранжевого налета, и металл начинает разрушаться. При этом другие металлы окисляются без образования ржавчины. Получается, что ржавеет только железо.

Металл или изделия из металла, содержащие железо, ведь не обязательно должны быть подвержены коррозии или покрыты ржавчиной (то есть это не постоянный признак, а приобретаемый, возможный).
Хорошая была цепь, почти не ржавая, длиной метра два (Владислав Крапивин. Трое с площади Карронад).
Стоит у ней нормальная ограда, не ржавая, крепкая, чего еще? (Сергей Каледин. Записки гробокопателя).
Заякорив снова свой плотик, Пловец подплыл к самому корпусу судна и прикоснулся к его поверхности — холодный металл, не ржавый, гладкий как зеркало, с заполированными клёпками (Виталий Домбровский. Проект «Hydra Sapiens»).
Металл был очень старый, но не ржавый (Павел Шершнёв. Сборник рассказов).



Впрочем, ветхому жилищу великокняжескому придавали какую-то мрачность ржавое железо решеток, ограждающих окна<< Ржавчина появляется исключительно на железных изделиях, зачем повторять слово "железо" дважды? Должно быть так: "...мрачность ржавые решетки, ограждающие окна..."



Нет, это не плеоназм.
Большой толковый словарь русского языка (Грамота.ру
Металл
Простое вещество (или сплав), обладающее особым блеском, ковкостью, хорошей теплопроводностью и электропроводностью.
Слитки металла. Раскалённый металл. Плавить металл. Чёрные металлы (железо и его сплавы).
Благородные, драгоценные металлы (золото, серебро, платина).
Неблагородные металлы металлы, окисляющиеся на воздухе: медь, железо, свинец и др.
Редкоземельные металлы (скандий, иттрий, лантан и лантаноиды).
Цветные металлы (о всех металлах, кроме чёрных).
Щёлочноземельные металлы окислы которых придают воде щелочные свойства: литий, натрий, калий, рубидий, цезий.
2.
Изделия из таких веществ.
Выставка металла. Презренный металл.шутливое о деньгах.
3.
Резкая интонация, категорический тон речи.
В голосе звучал металл.
4.
металлорок
Ржавчина
Красно-бурый налёт на поверхности железа, образующийся вследствие окисления его под действием воздуха и влаги.
Ржавчина пошла по поверхности. Техника изъедена ржавчиной. Ружейный ствол покрылся ржавчиной. Предохранять от ржавчины. Снимать ржавчину.
Как видно из словарного определения, ржавчина — это состояние металла, когда он покрывается  налетом вследствии внешних воздействий.

Серж,  голос от меня. Но вы скажите мне, как можно было увидеть в этом сочетание плеоназм, то есть масло маясляное. Разве металл  всегда ржавый, то есть это сопутствующий признак металла?  В конце концов золото тоже металл.

Вы абсолютно правы! Но что поделать?! Пришлось подкрепить ответ данными из словаря, а не просто опровергать .

Металл не всегда ржавый, но "ржавость" действительно сопутствующий признак исключительно металла. Иными словами, ржавым можно назвать, допустим, лист, но нельзя сказать "ржавый металлический лист", ведь словом "ржавый" уже подразумевается металл, покрытый ржавчиной (контекстный синоним слова "железо"). Из этого следует, что "ржавый металл" — смысловая избыточность

@Арчи, я не очень понимаю ход ваших мыслей. Почему нельзя сказать "ржавый металлический лист"? Ржавчина, действительно, сопутствующий признак металла, железа. Но ржавчина появляется только при определенных условиях. Т.е. при воздействии определенных внешних факторов.Поэтому здесь нет плеоназма.

Ржавый — покрытый оксидом железа (ржавчиной). Ржавчина образуется только на железе, соответственно словом "ржавый" уже подразумевается, что предмет из железа. Говоря "ржавый металлический лист", вы подразумеваете "сделанный из железа и покрытый оксидом железа железный лист".

Железо может быть ржавом, так и не ржавом. Ржавчина образуется только вследствие окисления его под действием воздуха и влаги. Если ржавчина образуется только на железе, это не значит, что перед нами плеоназм.

Ага, а итоги могут быть как финальными, так и нефинальными (промежуточными), но от этого фраза "финальный итог" не перестает быть плеоназмом

Слово "итог" уже означает "конечный результат". Это два совершено разных понятия.

"конечного результата" не бывает, это плеоназм, ну да ладно. >>>Железо может быть ржавом, так и не ржавом.<<< Я уже вывел, что такое употребление подразумевает смысловую избыточность, а вы мне ответили: "Да, ржавчина образуется только на железе, но это все равно не плеоназм", тогда мы вычеркиваем из списка плеоназмов такие доблестные изречения, как "сливочное масло, сделанное из сливок" и "шерстяная шерсть, покрытая шерстью" ведь обязательно нужно уточнить, из чего сделано что-либо: без этого невозможно добиться понимания, поскольку прилагательные не предоставляют исчерпывающей информации

Прилагательное  "Шерстяной" уже означает сделан из шерсти. А если ржавчина образуется только на железе — это не значит, что это плеоназм.

ВВОДНАЯ ЧАСТЬ
  Времена не выбирают,
  В них живут и умирают.
  Большей пошлости на свете
  Нет, чем клянчить и пенять.
  Будто можно те на эти,
  Как на рынке, поменять.
  Что ни век, то век железный...
  Александр Кушнер (1936 год

ЖЕЛЕЗНЫЙ ВЕК
Железный век — эпоха в истории человечества, характеризующаяся распространением металлургии железа и изготовлением железных орудий. Самые ранние известные железные орудия появились в Передней Азии, Индии и в Южной Европе, где технология была известна уже на рубеже II и I тысячелетий до н. э. Начало железного века обычно относят к началу I тысячелетия до н. э. (IX–VII века до н. э.). Окончание железного века ряд исследователей относят к I веку н. э.
Но неужели все железо раньше было ржавым?
ЗАЩИТА ОТ КОРРОЗИИ
Начиналось всё с банального обмазывания железных поверхностей жиром и маслами. Иногда прибегали к золочению или посеребрению изделий. Более «технологичным» методом считалось применение порошка — смеси их золотой и оловянной пыли, которые наносились на защищаемую поверхность (изделие потом прокаливалось, а на его поверхности образовывался спёкшийся защитный слой).
ОТВЕТ
ОБЩИЙ СМЫСЛ ОТВЕТА на этот вопрос такой. Есть умозрительные рассуждения, основанные на знаниях химии.   И есть реальные тексты, где встречаются выражения ржавый металл, ржавое железо. Они не несут никакой избыточной информации, а говорят о том, что перед нами старое железо с нарушенным слоем защитного покрытия.  Соответственно, ни о каком плеоназме речи идти не может.
А иначе мы доказываем, что белое это белое, а черное это черное, а это является задачей, не имеющей смысла.

Ржавый металл — не плеоназм! Ржавый  металл — это всегда железо, покрытое ржавчиной, что хорошо определяется по красно-бурому налету.

Предложения со словосочетанием «ржавый металл»
Между горами ржавого металла (= железа) пробиралась маленькая фигура, шлёпая по чёрным лужам грязи.
Джейми Смарт, Флембер, 2019

Может, ржавое железо — это плеоназм? Тоже нет!  Это всего лишь старое железо с нарушенным покрытием от коррозии.

Предложения со словосочетанием «ржавое железо»
Здесь были старые доски, целая куча ржавого железа с какой-то крыши, валялись огромные железные ворота...
Мария Кикоть, Исповедь бывшей послушницы, 2017

Что делали из железа

Изделия из железа имели защитное покрытие, но их все же называли железными.
Предложения со словосочетанием «делать из железа»
Иногда на ударном конце на цепи подвешивался сокрушительный металлический шар, хотя саму палицу тоже стали делать из железа.
Екатерина Монусова, История рыцарства. Самые знаменитые битвы, 2010
Чтобы защитить воина, кольчуги делали толще, из более массивных железных колец.
Валерий Шамбаров, Александр Невский. Ледовое побоище и другие подвиги непобедимого князя, 2020

Плеоназм или нет?
Да.
Почему?
Слово "ржавый" уже подразумевает наличие металла, или железа, так как ржавчина образуется исключительно на железе и его сплавах (сплавы мы исключаем, поскольку это не металлы). Иными словами, словосочетание "ржавый металл" становится избыточным, поскольку "ржавость" всегда ассоциируется с предметами из железа. Говоря "ржавый металл", вы подразумеваете "созданное из железа и покрытое оксидом железа железо", что неверно.
Как правильно употреблять?
Вместо выражения "ржавый металл" следует использовать слова, которые уточняют его форму. Например, можно сказать "ржавый лист", или "ржавый слиток", или "ржавая металлоконструкция", или "ржавые решётки" — как вам угодно.
А что со сплавами?
Сплавы называть ржавыми корректно (например, ржавая сталь), поскольку тут нужно уточнить, что это именно сплав, а не металл.

Груда ржавого металла лежала на дороге. Попробуем уточнить форму? Ржавая груда лежала на дороге? Ржавая куча лежала на дороге? Или как?

"Груда" и "куча" говорят не о форме предмета, а о количестве предметов, лежащих рядом. Как я понял, вы хотите сказать, что это какой-то мусор, поэтому я бы написал "ржавая груда металлолома/лома"

А ещё лучше "груда ржавого лома"

Это не металлолом это куча нормальных металлических предметов, только ржавых. Можно написать груда ржавых предметов. Но тогда возникает другой плеоназм. Ведь если ржавый, то обязательно - предмет. Плеоназм.

Вы слишком абстрактно пишете: предметом может быть что угодно, от монеты до танка. С таким посылом можно просто написать "груда ржавого" (в словосочетании слово "ржавый" выступает в роли существительного), и вы не потеряете ни капли смысла

Посыл вот какой - шероховатый объект, ржавый предмет, угловатая сущность - все это плеоназмы по вашей логике. Так как ржавым\угловатым\шероховатым может быть только предмет\объект\сущность

Я не знаю, где вы усмотрели такой посыл. Мой вопрос: "ржавый металл — плеоназм или нет?" Я умозаключил, что слово ржавый несёт сразу два смысла (созданный из железа и покрытый окислами железа), поэтому некорректно использовать данное слово в сочетании со словом "металл", поскольку дублируется значение "созданный из металла". Даже если рассудить без части смысловой избыточности, то фразы типа "ржавое железо" несут недостаточную смысловую нагрузку: автор описывает сам не знает что, зато не забывает упомянуть, что это что-то покрыто ржавчиной и сделано из железа. Вам это не кажется странным?

Не существует причин, по которым это словосочетание может не быть плеоназмом. Возможно, в расширенных словосочетаниях такая логика не подходит, поскольку изделие нельзя считать железным по умолчанию — в таком случае уточнить, железный ли объект или перед нами сплав, нужно, т. е. в словосочетаниях повторы типа "ржавый металлический лист" уместны, но суть вопроса не в этом.

Я вслед за вами умозаключил, что слово ржавый несёт сразу два смысла (являющийся предметом и покрытый окислами железа), поэтому некорректно использовать данное слово в сочетании со словом "предмет", поскольку дублируется значение "являющийся предметом". Ржавый предмет некорректно. Шероховатый объект некорректно. Бесформенная сущность некорректно. Миллион словосочетаний - плеоназмы по этой логике.

Хотя "ржавое железо" дает нам добавочную информацию, что это не ржавый предмет, так как железо это не предмет. То же и с "ржавым предметом" он дает добавочную информацию, что это предмет, а не ржавое железо. То есть избыточного смысла нет. Но в других словосочетаниях он есть, например "шероховатый объект". Если шероховатый, то уж точно объект. Избыточность. Таких словосочетаний миллион.
